# How can I set the default double click action in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, defaultview

How can I make Visual Studio default to View Source when you double-click the `Form1.cs`.  I prefer to make View Source the default of double-click than View Designer.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Right click the file in the Solution Explorer, choose "Open With...", select the CSharp Editor, and click the "Set as Default" button.

Answer (score 12):

Right click a form file and click "Open With...". Pick your desired designer to open as default (in this case "CSharp Editor" or "Microsoft Visual Basic Editor") and click "Set as Default". Voila.

Answer (score 1):

with this attribute myClass will open in the code editor and not the designer:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
public class myClass : Form
{

}
```