# The class XXX can be designed, but is not the first class in the file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have this class and internal class as part of a namespace, like this (Just removed and replaced some code and namespace declarations:

```
namespace X.Y.MessageHandlers.AsxActivity
{
    public class AsxActivityAliveEventMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<AsxActivityAliveEvent>
    {
        private const double INTERVAL = 10000;
        public static bool AsxConnected { get; set; }
        private static Dictionary<String, TagTimer> _connectionTimers = new Dictionary<string, TagTimer>();

        public void Handle(AsxActivityAliveEvent message)
        {
              ...
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
              ...
        }

        static void NotifyClients(AsxActivityAliveEvent message)
        {
              ...
        }
    }

    internal class TagTimer : Timer
    {
        public object Tag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Whenever I double-click my "AsxActivityAliveEventMessageHandler.cs" from the solution explorer, Visual studio pops up a window I've never seen before that gives me
the following message:

> To prevent possible data loss before loading
>   the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

This is followed by this explanation:

> The class TagTimer can be designed, but is not the first class in the
>   file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the
>   file. Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file
>   and try loading the designer again.

Tried changing the class TagTimer from internal to public to private, but error does not seem do budge. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double clik the file, VS tries to open the designer if there are designable classes in the file. You can either [change the default open action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633191/how-can-i-set-the-default-double-click-action-in-visual-studio), or move the `TagTimer` class above the `AsxActivityAliveEventMessageHandler`.

Another solution is to open the file not by double clicking, but by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I'm stuck with another question; Why is this class made to be a designable class?

Comment: I guess because `Timer` derives from `Component`.